# How do I work around the Oracle DBLinks limit in Entity Framework?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I am creating an MVC application using Oracle's Entity Framework, and am writing a bit of code to iterate through all relevant DBLinks and testing them out, returning a grid of results (success/fail). My problem is that after using the fourth DBLink, I get an error "ORA-02020: too many database links in use".

I have tried to explicitly close each DBLink after using it ("alter session close database link LinkName"), but I then receive an error "ORA-02080: database link is in use".

I have tried issuing "COMMIT" statement before attempting to close the DBLink, but that doesn't change the error ("database link is in use").

I have tried to closing the database connection, but I still receive the "database link is in use" error when I create a new connection and try to close the DBLink.

Unfortunately, increasing the number of DBLinks available (open_links, open_links_per_instance) is not an option.

Has anyone seen this with Entity Framework and discovered a solution? Does anyone have any ideas of what else to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VICTORY! I found that if I set "Pooling=false" in my connection string, then this error goes away in all of the offending scenarios. This is viable for me since this is just used to test the DBLinks on demand, so I can safely turn off pooling in this scenario. Thanks so much for your responses. I was ready to turn in the towel and admit defeat

Answer (score 0):

To see how many `db links` are open i syour session use the `GV$DBLINK` view

```
select DB_LINK from GV$DBLINK;

DB_LI
-----
LEDRP
YDO
```

To close a [`db link`](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25494_01/ds_appdev002.htm) you must do two things.

First `commit` or `rollback` the transaction. Note that even if you do not change anything a transaction is open due to the use of the `DB LINK`.

Second you must [`CLOSE DATABASE LINK`](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25494_01/ds_appdev002.htm) using the `ALTER SESSION` statement.

```
rollback;
ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK LEDRP;
```

You see, that link is closed and appears not in the view:

```
select DB_LINK from GV$DBLINK;

DB_LI
-----
YDOV
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but these are all things I already tried (see original post). No luck.

Comment: @ameritrash pls describe your *no luck* a bit. For me this works fine in 11.2 as demonstrated.

Comment: `var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select * from dual@DBLINKNAME").ToList(); // ToList so it will actually execute!`
`dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ROLLBACK"); // success`
`dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter session close database link DBLINKNAME"); // get "ORA-02080: database link is in use".`

Comment: the error is the same ("ORA-02080: database link is in use") if I use the  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection directly as well. so it's not entity framework specific as I thought.

Comment: I also tried closing the connection explicitly and closing the session on a new connection. still no luck. sadly.

Comment: Well this simple means @ameritrash there exists one or more *other* session with  *open* transaction using the same `db link`. You must find them all and `rollback` them before you may close the `db link`.